# Have to analyze a folder and do things with it: java

Tags: java

First of all, this is not trying to get someone to do my homework. I'm just trying to get people to HELP me with my homework. Moving forward.
I really wish I could do this by myself without help, but I believe there are integral specific vocabulary words that I do not know of that prevent me from knowing how to do this.

Folders roog = new Folders("C:\Users\Nick\AndroidStudioProjects");

So "Folders" is supposed to be a class where I can basically analyze folders and do certain functions.
Here is one of the things I'm supposed to do:
System.out.println(roog);
That will print a list of all the files and folders there.
So therefore, in my class, I have to do that somewhere.

My issue with this is: it doesn't tell me where in "Folders" to go. So how am I supposed to make it go print out the list in the file "C:\Users\Nick\AndroidStudioProjects" if it doesn't tell you where in the class to go?

2. System.out.println(roog.countFiles());
   So I'm supposed to make a method called countFiles, that counts the amount of files above? Seems pretty simple, make an int and do a "listfiles().length". As long as I have that right. So is that right?
3. System.out.println(roog.countFiles("java"));
   Counts the number of times the word "java" is in a file name.
   Would I do this?:

   .endsWith("java")?
   or ".contains("java")?"
4. System.out.println(roog.countInFiles("public")); 
   So I have to OPEN the files. How do I open them? And then I think I would know how to count them based on previous problems. I just don't know what to "use" to open files.

Thanks!

Comment: The standard Java `File` class will help you. But please include your implementation of your `Folder` class. As it stands, this question seems like  you haven't attempted to start your homework. Hint: You need to override `toString()` to do `System.out.println(roog);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `System.out.println(roog)` will not give you list of all files and folders rather it will print and address reference of the Folders class object e.g. : Fgo@434$

Solution:
Integrate the following code in your source code file method to list

```
public void getAllcontent(){
File dir = new File("dir");

        System.out.println("All content in Folders roog directory");
        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
        }
}
```

2. You are going correct, and to enhance it more using Java 8 you can also use:

   Files.list(Paths.get("your path")).count();
3. you can use either of the `.endsWith("java")? or ".contains("java")` depending on what you want
   whereas former can be use to check the type of files(`.java`), the latter will check files with the name java as well(`MyJavaprogram.java`).
4. For opening the file and checking "public" occurrence you can use the buffered read

-->     `BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File.txt"));`

and traverse using:

-- >     `while ((nextLine=inputReader.readLine()) != null)`

and check your string using:

-->    `nextLine.equals("public")`

Please read a little about BufferedReader in Java (wont take more than 5-10mins)